# Mapping using Mapforce

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, map-force

This is the structure snipped i get with my input file

```
<fields>
    <field>
        <name>CompanyID</name>
        <values>
            <value>12345</value>
        </values>
    </field>
    <field>
        <name>DivisionID</name>
        <values>
            <value>100</value>
        </values>
    </field>
</fields>
```

Am trying to map it to my company structure which we can use across for our reporting application

```
<EmployeeID /> ->This should map to CompanyID from my input file
<DivisionID /> -> This should map to DivisionID from my input file
```

However when I load up the 2 xml in Mapforce
my input schema shows[image]

How do I map a collection from input file to a specific element in my output file.

The resulting XSLT would be used in a C# code

Comment: Do you actually want the collection or just the values?  For example the following XPath will select the CompanyID.   /*[local-name()='fields' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='field' and namespace-uri()=''][name="CompanyID"]/*[local-name()='values' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='value' and namespace-uri()='']/text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Filter component. Here a mapping based on your input.

[image: The mapping]

You should have this output:

[image: output]